# How to setup MariaDB Portable?

Tags: mariadb

The first question is: where is my.ini of the version 10.6.5?

I used mariadb-10.1.22. Download the zip file, unzip. Path like

```
D:\Servers\mysql\mariadb-10.1.22-winx64
```

Find my-medium.ini in root,

```
D:\Servers\mysql\mariadb-10.1.22-winx64\my-medium.ini
```

Change to my.ini, make some changes needed.

```
D:\Servers\mysql\mariadb-10.1.22-winx64\my.ini
```

Intall to service

```
D:\Servers\mysql\mariadb-10.1.22-winx64\bin\mysqld --install
```

But now, there is no my-medium.ini, nor my-xxx.ini. And the MySQL service cannot start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_install_dbexe/
This utility is older than 10.1, it debuted in 5.2

my.ini will in your datadir, which you specify on the mysql_install_db.exe command line . If you do not specify anything, data directory will be named 'data', and it will be next to the 'bin' directory.

Those my-medium.ini and friends were many years old. Now you're better off using defaults. you can set innodb_buffer_pool_size to whatever you wish, and maybe innodb_log_file_size, those are the most important ones.